# My neighbor is convinced that he is going to die. (Decode)

Tags: mathematics, word

So I live in a pretty crazy neighborhood, whoever designed it was pretty particular. All the houses are square, and arranged in a perfect grid, also the designer must have been rich because this neighborhood is massive - my one friend, Horton, says that it is infinite.. but I don't know about that.

Anyway, my crazy neighbor John has been holed up in his house tracking all the people moving in and out of the neighborhood, and he swears there is something 'bigger' going on here. He's always been a bit of a conspiracy nut, but he's got dozens and dozens of maps of our neighborhood all covered in strange markings. Some of the maps go back years! He claims something crazy is happening soon, after he, presumably, dies.

Can you help me? Is my neighbor going to die? What's happening soon? And who designed this neighborhood!??

I've included a map of the neighborhood. I've shown what houses are currently occupied, and I've marked where John lives in red. I'm really at a loss!

[image: The neighborhood]

Thanks!

Hint:

> I went back and tried to ask him what was going on, but he was inconsolable, he keeps muttering about how many neighbors *he* has. I asked him about Martin (a mutual friend of ours), who lives with three other people a long ways off from everyone else and he yelled; 'They're fine, they're ALWAYS fine - don't you get it!??' before wandering off muttering about something in three years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This puzzle is describing

> [Conway's Game Of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

Will your neighbor die?

> Yup. See the GIF in the next spoiler.

What's happening soon?

> The houses all spell LIFE. [image]

Who designed this neighborhood?

> The man, the myth, and the legend: **John Horton** Conway. Notice his first and middle names were used in the description.

Comment: It's worth noting the man's middle name.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thank you. I agree that was worth mentioning.

Comment: Haha aww, too easy maybe!